# Determine the exact value of the expression cos(Arcsec(4/3))

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Ok Sec theta is 4/3 which is r/x. So then y = 1 (I think). But I don't know how to get the exact value from the question. My answer wound up being Cos theta = 3. I'm not seeing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos\sec^{-1}(4/3) = \cos\cos^{-1}(3/4) = 3/4$$